# What is the daily limit of manually executed google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, time-limiting, quotas

In the documentation for developers ([here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)) written about this error
**Service using too much computer time for one day**
that

> This indicates that the script exceeded the total allowable execution time for one day. It most commonly occurs for scripts that run on a trigger, which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.

And there is a daily limit for triggers total runtime (1hr for basic account).
But where can I get the limitation for manual executed script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the limit is the same regardless of whether the script is manually executed or executed from a trigger; the limit is simply applied to your account, however you run the script.

Comment: Despite this part? - **which have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.**

Comment: You right, sorry, missed that bit. Looking at the quotas page it doesn't talk about a limit for script executed manually. I wonder if there is a limit - we need someone to spend all day manually running a script every 6 mins!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here: "Daily quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window; the exact time of this refresh, however, varies between users." I don't think Google publicly announces exactly what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I run script on the sidebar that request calculation on the server side which stops after 300 seconds and the sidebar starts it again. This engine worked more than 12 hours without any fails. So, I suppose that there is no any limit for 'manually' executed scripts.